# How to solve system equations that are composed of fractions

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to figure how to solve this particular system of equations.

$$
A = \frac{1}{x}, B = \frac{1}{y}
$$

$$
\frac{12}{x}-\frac{12}{y} = 7\\
   \frac{3}{x}+\frac{4}{y} = 0
$$

Comment: Make the substitution $B = 1/y$, and forget the $C$.

Comment: Then $12A - 12B = 7, 3A + 4B = 0$. Solve $A$ and $B$, then solve $x = 1/A, y = 1/B$.

Comment: @Yuki.F I'm kind of confused. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Now you substitute $A = 1/x, B = 1/y$ into the 2 equations you have, so the equations become what I typed above. Then use eliminations to get the value of $A$ and $B$ -- like what @lennon310 did in his response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$12A - 12B = 7$         (1)

$12A + 16B = 0$         (2)

Use (1) - (2) : $B = -1/4$

then pass $B$ to (2) (or (1)),  you can get $12A - 16 \cdot 1/4 = 0$, so $A = 1/3$).

Comment: after you get $B$ you can pass the value to either (1) or (2) to solve $A$

Comment: Does it matter where we pass it on? And how did $-1/4$ become $1/4$?

Comment: it doesn't matter, you can pass it to (1) too: $12A - 12(-1/4) = 7$ and get the same result. For (2) it is $12A + 16(-1/4) = 12A - 16(1/4)$

Comment: And in $(1)$ are we eliminating $12B$ to isolate $12A$?

Comment: yup, or in fact it is adding $12B$ on both side of the equation (1) to isolate $12A$

Comment: Adding $12B$ in order to cancel $12B$ in $(1)$, that means we have to add $12B$ to $7+12$?

Comment: It is $12A - 12B + 12B = 7 + 12B$

Comment: is $12B(-1/4)$ same as $12*(-0.25)=-3$, then $(-3)+3=0$ and $7+3=10$ what do we do with $12A$?

Comment: You need to add $-3$ on both side not $3$, so it's $12A - (-3) + (-3) = 7 + (-3)$

Comment: I apologise. I did put $(-3)$ in the begging, but changed it to $3$. Anyway. $12A = 4$ by simplifying the equation $12A/12A = 4 / 12$  we get $A = 3$ or $A = 1/3$

Comment: $A = 1/3$ so $x = 3$